# dollar escape? pay me $$owed

Tags: php, escaping

I ran into a block of code that executes print with double quotes around the argument. The argument contained a variable that was seemingly escaped by a dollar sign. Is that how a variable is called inside double quotes in php?

`print("$$owed");`

Here's the full block from the source:

```
<html>

 <head>

 <title>Loans</title>

 </head>


 <body>

 <?php

 $interest_rate = .14;

 function YouOweMe($cost, $interest_rate) {

 $weekly_payment = ($cost*$interest_rate);

 print "You better pay me $$weekly_payment every week, or else!";

 }

<font color="#000000">YouOweMe($cost, $interest_rate);

 ?>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I had to strip the numbers.  So annoying.

Anyway, ...  What doesn't make sense to me is that `$$owed` is supposed to, what?  Create a new variable from a separate variable that contains a string `'owed'`?  That doesn't seem practical in any situation.  Isn't `$$owed` just to get a dollar sign before the amount?

Comment: That right there is a variable variable - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: `variable variables` is probably one of the reason [Jeff Atwood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) wrote [The PHP Singularity](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/06/the-php-singularity.html) in his [Coding Horror blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog) recently.

Comment: Wow, lots of confusion in the answers.  Try this in your console.  `$owed = 'test'; print "$$owed";` Will print `$test`. The first `$` is a literal and the sec belongs to the variable.

Comment: I don't know that they were attempting a variable variable. It doesn't make sense in context. http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/php_tutorial_for_beginners/#Functions . I have strong reason to believe my phone isn't displaying a character.

Comment: Thanks, ken white.  I enjoyed reading that article.  I didn't see an alternative, though.  Is Jeff Aswood a fan of Ruby? Maybe Node.js?

Comment: @Michael - Please write your own answer, so we can vote for it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example to understand variable variables :

```
<?php
   $var = "test";
   $test = "hey !";
   echo "$$var";   //$test
   echo "${$var}"; //hey !
   echo '$$var';   //$$var
?>
```

Edited according to comments.

Comment: No, in my console this prints `$test`.

Comment: You need to say `echo "${$var}";`

Comment: Ow, right, it works only with `${$var}`. Sorry for my bad memory !

Comment: With `echo "$$test";` or even `echo "$${$var}";`

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, a variable is escaped with `$` when inside a string defined with double quotes. This does NOT work with single quotes.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on what he asked then. It seed like he wanted conformation that variables were escaped with `$` in php?

Comment: He's curious why the double `$` was there

Comment: Oh! There are two $ there because one of them is an actual '$' character, and the other one escapes the variable

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on a php-ready device. What does `$` do inside single quotes?

Comment: Nothing, it just prints as itself. `echo "$owed" ` would print the value of `owed`, where `echo '$owed'` would print '$owed', the string literal.

Comment: @dykeag Yeah, see that's the thing....  I figure, if `$` is supposed to escape for a variable, it should have to be escaped, itself, so that php understands it isn't preceding a variable.  For example `I have /$5.00.`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "world"; 

echo "Hello ${string}"; 
#### outputs "Hello World"
```

That is how you put a variable into a string (you need the double quotes).

What you have is variable-variable. You can call a variable `$foo` by using a string with `foo` in it.

```
$string = 'foo';
$foo = 'hello world';
echo "I say, ${$string}";
```

Would output "hello world.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to use variables inside double quotes, some common ways are

1. `print("$owed")` will print the value of `$owed`
2. `print("$$owed")` is called a "variable variable" (as linked previously)

   ```
    $owed = "test";
    $test = 16;
    print("$$owed");
   ```

   will print out "$test".
3. Another use of this comes in the form of `print("${$owed}")`, which takes the value of `$test` and uses it as the variable name.

I strongly advise you to use single quotes and concatenate the variables needed, as it saves the time for evaluating variables in out, e.g.:

```
$owed = 42;
print('The value is: ' . $owed);
```

lg,

flo

Comment: That isn't a variable variable in double quotes. Did you try your example? It prints `$test`, not `16`.

Comment: My answer has the proper syntax. The brackets are needed, for example: print("${$owed}");

Comment: If you can verify your answer, I can accept it because of the bit of advice on what I actually should be doing.